# Segmentation fault happened in Linux but works in Mac

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, xcode

I have a c code which wrote in my Mac laptop in Xcode but it didn't work in Linux system.

I run this code by two ways:

1.One is run in Eclipse but the while loop didn't look like finish.  Please find the message below:

> Please wait while calculating...

But not more message in the console. It looks like while loop can't finish by some reason.

2.The second way is that I complier the code directly in Linux environment by the command:

> cc -std=c99 main.c -o main

Then run by the command:

> ./main

The message shows that:

> Please wait while calculating... Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I checked by gdb

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00007ffff7a9bd4a in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

My data is saved in:

> /home/alan_yu/workspace/scandi.csv

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <time.h>

char **split(char *line, char sep, int fields) {

    char **r = (char **)malloc(fields * sizeof(char*));

    int lptr = 0, fptr = 0;

    r[fptr++] = line;

    while (line[lptr]) {

        if (line[lptr] == sep) {

            line[lptr] = '\0';

            r[fptr] = &(line[lptr+1]);

            fptr++;

        }

        lptr++;

    }

    return r;

}

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)

{

    return *(double *)a > *(double *)b ? 1 : -1;

}

#define LINE_SIZE 1000000

#define EXPECTED_STOCK_SIZE 10000000

void calculate2(char * fileName) {

     printf("Please wait while calculating...\n");

    // Open the file for reading.

    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    // maximun size of the line to read.

    // memory allocation for the line to read.

    char* line = malloc(LINE_SIZE);

//    char **stockNameArray = malloc( sizeof(char *) * EXPECTED_STOCK_SIZE);

//    int stockNameArrayPos = 0;

    double *bidArray = malloc( sizeof(double) * EXPECTED_STOCK_SIZE );

    int bidArrayPos = 0;

    double *askArray = malloc( sizeof(double) * EXPECTED_STOCK_SIZE);

    int askArrayPos = 0;

    double *spreadArray = malloc( sizeof(double) * EXPECTED_STOCK_SIZE);

    int spreadArrayPos = 0;

    double sum=0;

    int i=0,j=0;

    while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file)!= NULL){

    //  printf("Please wait while ...%d\n ", j);
        j++;
        char **fields = split(line, ',', 15);

        const char * volvbEquity = "VOLVB SS Equity";

        int comp = strcmp(fields[0], volvbEquity);

        if (comp == 0) {

            double bidValue = atof(fields[2]);

            double askValue = atof(fields[3]);

            bidArray[bidArrayPos++] = bidValue;

            askArray[askArrayPos++] = askValue;

            if (askValue - bidValue > 0) {

                double spreadValue = ((askValue - bidValue) / (askValue + bidValue) * 20000);

                spreadArray[spreadArrayPos++] = spreadValue;

                sum = sum + spreadValue;

            }

        }

    }


    //quick sort the spread

    qsort(spreadArray, spreadArrayPos, sizeof(double), cmpfunc);

    int mediumPos;

    double mean;

    double medium;

    if(spreadArrayPos % 2 == 0) {

        mediumPos = spreadArrayPos / 2;

        medium = (spreadArray[mediumPos] + spreadArray[mediumPos+1]) / 2;

    } else {

        mediumPos = (spreadArrayPos)/2 + 1;

        medium = spreadArray[mediumPos];

    }

    mean = sum / spreadArrayPos;

    printf("Please find mean and medium %f %f\n", mean, medium);

    free(bidArray);

    free(askArray);

    free(spreadArray);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    calculate2("/home/alan_yu/workspace/scandi.csv");

    return(0);

}
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please try to narrow down the code to the parts that are relevant. You can do this by running in a debugger, which will catch the crash and help you locate it in your code.

Comment: Also, you have barely any error checking, you allocate over 240 megabytes of memory, and you have multiple memory leaks.

Comment: You might like to read this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and then take the efforts to follow the appropriate steps proposed to narrow down or even solve your issue(s). If having done so and there still are any open questions, please feel free to come back here.

Comment: `while (line[lptr]) {` has no protection from `lptr >= fields`.

Comment: `int cmpfunc()` is wrong in that `int cmpfunc(x,x)` does not return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void split(char *line, char sep, char **fields) {

    int lptr = 0, fptr = 0;

    fields[fptr++] = line;

    while (line[lptr]) {

        if (line[lptr] == sep) {

            line[lptr] = '\0';

            fields[fptr] = &(line[lptr+1]);

            fptr++;

        }

        lptr++;

    }
}

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
    return *(double *)a > *(double *)b ? 1 : -1;
}

#define LINE_SIZE 1000000

#define EXPECTED_STOCK_SIZE 10000000

#define COLUMN_NUM 15

void calculate2(char * fileName) {

     printf("Please wait while calculating...\n");

    // Open the file for reading.
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    // maximun size of the line to read.
    // memory allocation for the line to read. 
    char* line = malloc(LINE_SIZE);

//    char **stockNameArray = malloc( sizeof(char *) * EXPECTED_STOCK_SIZE);
//    int stockNameArrayPos = 0;

    double *bidArray = malloc( sizeof(double) * EXPECTED_STOCK_SIZE );

    int bidArrayPos = 0;

    double *askArray = malloc( sizeof(double) * EXPECTED_STOCK_SIZE);

    int askArrayPos = 0;

    double *spreadArray = malloc( sizeof(double) * EXPECTED_STOCK_SIZE);

    int spreadArrayPos = 0;

    double sum=0;

    int i=0,j=0;

    while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file)!= NULL){

    //  printf("Please wait while ...%d\n ", j);
        j++;
        char **fields = malloc(sizeof(char *) * COLUMN_NUM);
        split(line, ',', fields);

        const char * volvbEquity = "VOLVB SS Equity";

        int comp = strcmp(fields[0], volvbEquity);

        if (comp == 0) {

            double bidValue = atof(fields[2]);

            double askValue = atof(fields[3]);

            bidArray[bidArrayPos++] = bidValue;

            askArray[askArrayPos++] = askValue;

            if (askValue - bidValue > 0) {

                double spreadValue = ((askValue - bidValue) / (askValue + bidValue) * 20000);

                spreadArray[spreadArrayPos++] = spreadValue;

                sum = sum + spreadValue;

            }

        }

        // free memory for fields.
        free(fields);

    }

    // free memory for the line variable.
    free(line);

    //quick sort the spread
    qsort(spreadArray, spreadArrayPos, sizeof(double), cmpfunc);

    int mediumPos;
    double mean;
    double medium;

    if(spreadArrayPos % 2 == 0) {
        mediumPos = spreadArrayPos / 2;
        medium = (spreadArray[mediumPos] + spreadArray[mediumPos+1]) / 2;

    } else {
        mediumPos = (spreadArrayPos)/2 + 1;
        medium = spreadArray[mediumPos];
    }

    mean = sum / spreadArrayPos;

    printf("Please find mean and medium %f %f\n", mean, medium);

    free(bidArray);

    free(askArray);

    free(spreadArray);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    calculate2("/home/alan_yu/workspace/scandi.csv");

    return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value of `fopen`! I would suggest doing the same thing for `malloc`, <strike>but it's much less likely that `malloc` is failing due to a missing file or typographical error</strike> **particularly if you're allocating large chunks**! You wouldn't want to dereference a null pointer, right?

I'm assuming each line has at least four comma-separated fields, because you're using `fields[3]`. You should probably work out how to guard against using uninitialised values here. I'd start by re-engineering `split` so that you have some terminal `NULL` value or something in its output (and while we're on that topic, don't forget to `free` the return value).

Is it possible that you might be dividing by zero? That'd be something else you need to guard against.

Shouldn't `cmpfunc` return `0` when items are equal? I've seen implementations crash when return values for comparison functions for `qsort` and `bsearch` are inconsistent.

You claimed below in a comment that your lines have fifteen commas. This implies that **you have sixteen fields** (count them below), since the number of fields is `n+1` where `n` is the number of separators.

```
field1, field2, field3, field4,
field4, field6, field7, field8,
field9, field10,field11,field12,
field13,field14,field15,field16
```

There are fifteen commas and sixteen fields in this table. **You're only allocating enough for fifteen fields, however. This is a buffer overflow, more typical undefined behaviour.**

Comment: Hi Seb. Thanks for your reply. It looks like the programming crash in the split function after I using the debug. But I didn't find out the problem. The data have 15 comma.

Comment: @AlanYu With that little bit of information provided I was able to provide an update to my answer. Let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, always run the program in `valgrind` if it is crashing.

It will not only tell you exactly what is wrong in your code, but also specify what code lines are responsible for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find out the problem comes from the

```
while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file)!= NULL){
char **fields = split(line, ',', 15);
```

I have changed it to

```
char **fields = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 15 * 10000);
while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file)!= NULL){
```

I haven't try to allocate a large memory to **fields after the while loop due to it takes too much memory to my machine.

It looks like under gcc compile that if I do:

```
while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, file)!= NULL){
char **fields = split(line, ',', 15);
```

It won't overwrite the **fields from last time. But it works in Mac

Not sure is that correct?

In the end, thanks for all of you guys help for my problem.